# Transactions on documentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have our data stored in documentdb. We do need to perform action that touch mutiple document in one transaction. Is there a way to perform a sqlserver like transaction on documentDB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you execute clientside actions every action is executed independent of a transaction. It is not possible to create a transaction from the client side actions.

To execute mutiple actions in one transaction you need to create a documentDB stored procedure. All actions in a document Stored Procedure are executed similar to a transaction. 
All actions are executed and if one of them fails, all actions are rolled backed.

For more information how to create and execute stored procedures see:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/

Answer (score 4):

Transactions are handled via stored procedures. The operations within a stored procedure will happen within a transaction.

Just note that, within a stored procedure, any documents you touch can only be within a single collection (or a single partition within a partitioned collection).